# Is it possible to call a custom field from ACF or Pods into a function?

Tags: wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I am fluent in HTML and CSS but not so much in PHP. Any help would be appreciated.

I have a custom function in Wordpress as seen below:

```
function prefix_calculation_global_calculation_vars( $vars ) {
    return array(
        'setup_cost' => 200,
    );
}
add_filter( 'pewc_calculation_global_calculation_vars', 'prefix_calculation_global_calculation_vars' );
```

Is it possible to call an Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) field or a Pods field and have the value inserted into the function above where the 200 is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing get_the_ID() works you could try this:

```
function prefix_calculation_global_calculation_vars( $vars ) {
    return array(
        'setup_cost' => get_field('setup_cost', get_the_ID()),
    );
}
add_filter( 'pewc_calculation_global_calculation_vars', 'prefix_calculation_global_calculation_vars' );
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! EDIT: To clarify, in case someone else needs this, I replaced `get_the_ID()` with the ID number of the custom post.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to grab it via the $wpdb->postmeta table

```
<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'setup_cost', TRUE); ?>
```